# Variant Column Calculation

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

In source we have a variant column (events) and we need to sum up metrics (calls, impressions, leads, visits, etc.) in that column.
[image]

Metrics can vary in number. e.g. First 4 rows have 4 metrics, 5th row has 5 and 6th row has 3.

Here is target output required.
[image]

Here are source code to create table and insert sample data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE user_activity (
    ACTIVITY DATE,
    ID       NUMBER  , 
    NAME     VARCHAR , 
    EVENTS   VARIANT
);

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events) 
SELECT '2023-09-05'::date, 101, 'Pink Panther', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": "Y",   "visits": "Y",   "calls": "N",   "leads": "N" }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events) 
SELECT '2023-09-05'::date, 102, 'Pink Panther', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": "Y",   "visits": "Y",   "calls": "N",   "leads": "N" }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events)
SELECT '2023-09-05'::date, 103, 'Pink Panther', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": "Y",   "visits": "N",   "calls": "Y",   "leads": "N" }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events)
SELECT '2023-09-05'::date, 104, 'Pink Panther', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": "Y",   "visits": "N",   "calls": "N",   "leads": "Y" }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events)
SELECT '2023-09-06'::date, 105, 'Pink Panther', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": "Y",   "visits": "N",   "calls": "N",   "leads": "Y",   "service": "Y" }');

INSERT INTO user_activity (activity, id, name, events)
SELECT '2023-09-06'::date, 106, 'Pink Panther', PARSE_JSON('{   "imps": "Y",   "visits": "Y",   "calls": "N" }');
```

We will add 1 if value of metric is "Y" else 0.

Here is my work in progress:

```
SELECT
    activity
  , name 
  , events AS total_events -- need help to calculate this
  , (CASE WHEN events:calls::string='Y'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS calls
  , (CASE WHEN events:imps::string='Y'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS imps
  , (CASE WHEN events:leads::string='Y'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS leads
  , (CASE WHEN events:visits::string='Y'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS visits
  , (CASE WHEN events:service::string='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS service
FROM user_activity,
lateral flatten(events) f
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1;
```

I need help to sum up metrics in **total_events** column as shown in target output.

Answer (score 0):

Try below if it helps

```
select*,OBJECT_DELETE(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*),'ACTIVITY','NAME')  total_events
    from(
     
    select 
    activity
      ,name 
      ,sum(calls) calls
      ,sum(imps) imps
      ,sum(leads) leads
      ,sum(visits) visits
      ,sum(service) service
      
    from (
        SELECT
            activity
          , name 
          , events AS total_events -- need help to calculate this
          , (CASE WHEN events:calls::string='Y'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS calls
          , (CASE WHEN events:imps::string='Y'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS imps
          , (CASE WHEN events:leads::string='Y'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS leads
          , (CASE WHEN events:visits::string='Y'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS visits
          , (CASE WHEN events:service::string='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS service
        FROM user_activity,
        lateral flatten(events) f
        GROUP BY 1,2,3
    )
    group by 1,2
);
```

Comment: Thanks @aditya, I updated query based on your suggestion but not there yet :)

Comment: @BeginnerDeveloper Give try to updated answer once, and let me know how it works

Answer (score 0):

Based on @aditia pawar suggestion, it is close but not exact what is required:

```
select 
    activity     as activity
  , name         as name
  , sum(calls)   as calls
  , sum(imps)    as imps
  , sum(leads)   as leads
  , sum(visits)  as visits
  , sum(service) as service
  , OBJECT_CONSTRUCT( 
                  'calls',   sum(a.calls::NUMBER(2,1)),
                  'imps',    sum(a.imps::NUMBER(2,1)),
                  'leads',   sum(a.leads::NUMBER(2,1)),
                  'visits',  sum(a.visits::NUMBER(2,1)),
                  'service', sum(a.service::NUMBER(2,1))
                  ) AS total_events
from (
    SELECT
        activity
      , name 
      , events AS events -- need help to calculate this
      , (CASE WHEN events:calls::string='Y'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS calls
      , (CASE WHEN events:imps::string='Y'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS imps
      , (CASE WHEN events:leads::string='Y'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS leads
      , (CASE WHEN events:visits::string='Y'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS visits
      , (CASE WHEN events:service::string='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS service
    FROM user_activity,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(events) f
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
) a
group by 1,2
order by 1,2,3;
```

[image]

Comment: Two bugs in above solution are:
1. For the metrics that does not exitst in source(events), we should not have in output column (total_events)
2. How can we make output column dynamic to have any NEW metrics that is included later on (without making any code changes). 
e.g. what if we get another metric "sales":
{   "imps": "Y",   "visits": "N",   "calls": "N",   "leads": "Y",   "service": "Y", "sales": "Y" }

Comment: Creating a separate ticket to discuss it (after making it simple).
Thanks everyone for your help